# PowerMock whenNew Not Returning Mocked Instance

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I'm trying to use PowerMock to snub out a call to Jackson ObjectMapper but for some reason it isn't working and I suspect it is related to whenNew not actually providing the mocked instance when it gets instantiated in the method being tested.

This is a legacy code base we can't really change so we are stuck using PowerMock to meet the test coverage requirements...

I have a method that has something like the following:

```
private void intakeDataFromUrl(URL url) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    DataDTO[] dataDtos = mapper.readValue(url, DataDTO[].class)

    // other code
}
```

In the unit test I am attempting to do the following:

```
@Test
public void test_intakeDataFromUrl() {

    DataDTO[] data = this.createMockData();

    ObjectMapper mapper = mock(ObjectMapper.clas);

    whenNew(ObjectMapper.clas)
        .withNoArguments()
        .thenReturn(mapper);

    // mock call to return mocked data
    doReturn(data)
        .when(mapper, "readValue", any(URL.class), any(DataDTO[].class))
}
```

But in the code being tested dataDtos is always null and then the next section of code always fails.

Edit:

Looks like this line is maybe the problem although looking at other examples it should work.

```
// mock call to return mocked data
doReturn(data)
    .when(mapper, "readValue", any(URL.class), any(DataDTO[].class))
```

I've also tried isA and eq on the last argument with no luck, still returns null.

Comment: Can you share the test class' definition? Is it annotated with `@PrepareForTest`?

Comment: I made an example out of the real code since it is not allowed to be shared, but the class is annotated with @PrepareForTest and it has the ObjectMapper.class along with the class being tested

Comment: The `doReturn` call **is** the issue. Should be `Mockito.when(mapper.readValue(..., ...)).thenReturn(...);`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50531594/8200937).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following use of `whenNew` with `ObjectMapper` works successfully:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ObjectMapper.class})
public class WtfTest {

    @Test
    public void test_intakeDataFromUrl() throws Exception {
        String in = "in";
        String out = "out";

        ObjectMapper mapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(ObjectMapper.class)
                .withNoArguments()
                .thenReturn(mapper);

        Mockito.when(mapper.readValue(in, String.class)).thenReturn(out);

        assertEquals(out, intakeDataFromUrl(in));
    }

    private String intakeDataFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(url, String.class);
    }
}
```

Although this example does not use `DataDTO`, it is otherwise consistent with your example and it is functional.